# Java design question

Tags: java, spring

I want users to go through objectmanager for all persistence operation, instead of using UserDao directly, how can I make UserDao not visible to users. I am using spring to inject Implementation into UserDao.

```
public class ObjectManager {

  public static UserDao USER_DAO;

  @Inject
  public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
     ObjectManager.USER_DAO = userDao;
  }
}

public interface UserDao extends GenericDAO<User,Long>{
  User findUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

what i am trying to achieve it that everyone follows one path to perform persistence operation, in my case it would be ObjectManager.USER_DAO.save(obj)..something like this instead of one developer doing userDao.save(obj)....the ObjectManger is purely for convenience. Any body can type objectManager. and the IDE will show a list of dao that are available

Comment: Can you describe why you want to hide the UserDao? What does the ObjectManager class do?

Comment: If you're exposing these classes to other developers, what's to stop them from directly accessing the underlying persistence layer and performing their operations that way?

Comment: I guess you are right, there is nothing to stop them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice: **don't do this**.

This would tightly couple your DAO classes to your central, static ObjectManager class for no obvious reason. This makes the code in your application hard to unit test, because static references like ObjectManager.USER_DAO.save(obj) can't be mocked. Also the application will be harder to maintain because any change to ObjectManager will hit nearly all your code (example future scenario: you want to move some DAO accessors out of the ObjectManager).

If you value testability and maintainability avoid global classes with static access.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of achieving this is to change the UserDao scope to "package" level and let ObjectManager (assuming ObjectManager is part of the same package) act as a facade to it. Since UserDao is not accessible outside of the package no other client can instantiate it.

But since you are using Spring, I believe you can't do this. One work around I think of is to inject the UserDao with [**inner bean definition**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-inner-beans) to ObjectManager. This way other code can't do a lookup using bean name or other cfg can't reference it.

Comment: can you give some code example of what do mean by "inline definition to ObjectManager. This way other code can't do a lookup using bean name or other cfg can't reference it."

Comment: updated the post by providing a link to reference doc. click on inner bean definition highlighted link

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add a layer between the persistence (DAO) layer and the service layer. I have a project where I do something similar, inserting a Repository layer.

When you have a layered application you can create a multi-module build and enforce dependencies between layers at build time. So the DAO layer is not on the compile-time classpath for the service layer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can make the Constructor private, Spring DI still will instantiate them using reflection.**

Your users (programmers using your api/classes) can still instantiate classes if they use reflection too, however the normal use of "new MyClass()" will give you compile time errors. But the question remains, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: what i am trying to achieve it that everyone follows one path to perform persistence operation, in my case it would be ObjectManager.USER_DAO.save(obj)..something like this instead of one developer doing userDao.save(obj)....the ObjectManger is purely for convenience. Any body can type objectManager. and the IDE will show a list of dao that are available

Comment: If the ObjectManager is just for convenience and doesn't add any behaviour then I don't see any harm in classes being able to access the DAOs directly if they choose to.

Comment: I see, like I said, the private constructor will work with Spring DI.